# What do you call the domains of a relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have noticed that for binary relations $R_2 \subseteq A \times B$, that the set A is called the domain and B is called the codomain.  What about other n-ary relations where n > 2?  For example, is there a standard name for the sets X, Y and Z for a relation $R_3 \subseteq X \times Y \times Z$?  Are they all just called domains?

Comment: I have yet to see a relation that's not binary or that can be translated into a binary action. With that said, one would expect that they would be considered just domains. Question: do you have a specific example in mind of a triplet relation?

Comment: I would say it depends largely on context, but you would generally only encounter binary relations in practice and they would be treated as binary relations even if multiple cartesian products are used, for example as is the case in a function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$, as a relation it is seen as a subset of $(\Bbb R\times \Bbb R)\times (\Bbb R\times \Bbb R)$

Comment: @Sentinel135 Ternary relations occur occasionally when it comes to database design/theory.

Comment: As an example, consider the predicate $x^2 + y^2 = z^2, x \in \mathbb{R} , y \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{R}$.  The set of solutions to this equation would be a ternary relation, where each triplet <x, y, z> represents a solution.

Comment: @JMoravitz: So the above ternary relation could be considered a binary relation on $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It could be worded that way, yes.  The question is I suppose what you want to receive the largest emphasis.  Heck, it could also be phrased as a binary relation on $\Bbb R^3\times \{true,~false\}$ where $(x,y,z)$ is related to "true" iff $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and false otherwise.

Comment: According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation , it is not unusual to call each of $X,Y,Z$ domains.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, I guess I was just idly wondering what these sets were called when the relation was not binary.  The feeling that I am getting from this discussion is that it is not usually something to worry about, since  most relations in practice are binary...

Comment: @benguin thanks, I have read that page but must have missed that bit, cheers!

Comment: @esotechnica It's the first bullet point after "The following considerations apply under either definition" in the Formal Definition section. It's a little buried in there :)